# Request.ServerVariables from a webservice (asmx)

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, .net-3.5, asmx

On my serverside pages (intranet environment), I use the following code to find out which user is using the page:

```
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
```

How do I use that command in a webservice (asmx file)?  I can't use the line above as I get a message saying that `Request is not declared`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables`...